# Cannot add server glassfish 4.1.2 in netbeans 8.1

Tags: netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

When trying to add Glassfish 4.1.2 server in Netbeans 8.1 IDE, I'm getting the following error message:

"Not a valid GlassFish Server installation"

JDK 1.7.0_67 on Windows XP used.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Remove any existing GlassFish 4.1.2 instance.
2. Exit NetBeans.
3. Rename `console-core`:
   `cd glassfish412/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/lib/
   mv console-core-4.1.2.jar console-core-4.1.jar`
4. Start NetBeans.
5. Add GlassFish 4.1.2 Server Instance back into NetBeans (detected as 4.1).
6. Rename `console-core` to its original name:
   `cd glassfish412/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/lib/
   mv console-core-4.1.jar console-core-4.1.2.jar`

Comment: I am having this problem. I installed glassfish 5.0. Im using Netbeans 8.0. This works for the same error. The server is detected but when you press next, its stacked, it does not continue. What will I do next? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release news](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/glassfish-412-released), Glassfish 4.1.2 requires JDK 7 u80 or newer:

> Minimum JDK required is JDK 7 u80.

Comment: installation JDK7 u80 doesn't help